# Removing Url in the webpage print in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a web app...all i want is whenever a candidate tries to print the webpage i should be able to prevent the printing of url in the footer of the printed page.normally whenever we print the webpage.the url is printed in the footer of the page. I know that we can prevent it by modifying the page setup properties.but as it is a live site..i cant go around the client systems.so i need some code that will remove the footer in the print

Regards,

Comment: Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts, or they will be removed.http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature of the browser. Each browser is a little different, but most have an option to show or hide the page url in the header or footer. ASP.NET has no control over this.